# How to delete rows with conditions in pandas if there is no index?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hi so I have a pandas DataFrame called finalresultyears_withoutcolums. Now I want to get rid of the rows which have the attribute 'None' within the total_points column. However I cannot do it with the drop method, as there is no index at the rows. What would be the right approach to do this?

[image: in pa]

Comment: `finalresultyears_withoutcolums[' total_points'].dropna()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Erfan's comment, you can use `dropna` method and specify the columns and whether you want to do it inplace or not:

```py
finalresultyears_withoutcolums.dropna(subset=['total_points'], inplace=True)
```

[Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html)